# Result of code execution depends on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer, breakpoints

I'm currently trying to scrape some content from a website with Puppeteer and vsCode.
And everything seems to work fine if I have a debug breakpoint on the evaluation line, but as soon as I deactivate the breakpoint I get `currentBuy = ' '` value, instead of the correct string value;

```
/* the code for the scrappingPage:
let scrappingBrowser = Puppeteer.launch();
let scrappingPage = scrappingBrowser.newPage();
await scrappingPage.goto(url);
*/

let currentBuy;
try {
    currentBuy = await scrappingPage.$eval('#market_commodity_buyrequests', (res) => res.innerText);
} catch {}

console.log(currentBuy);
```

Depending if I have set a breakpoint on the `currentBuy = await scrappingPage.$eval...` line or not, `currentBuy = " "` (a string containing 1 space) or the correct string.

I tried a couple things, like getting the JSHandle first and calculating it later. Or wrapping all in an external async function and waiting for its execution. But still the same results.

If I like to have the correct string value I need to interrupt the program at the "eval"-line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, it's [scraping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scraping) not [scrapping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrapping)

Comment: What page is it? Does it change the contents of `#market_commodity_buyrequests` dynamically? You might need to add some code to wait for the value to appear. When debugging with a breakpoint, the page has more time to load until your code runs.

Comment: the breakpoint is probably giving that time to load

Answer (score 1):

Looks like text is not appeared properly for element (it's in rendering state).

I suggest you to use my Puppeteer wrapper library for this case and wait for text value to stop changing.

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html#waitforvaluetostopchanging)

Code should look like

```js
import { waitForValueToStopChanging, getText } from 'bubanai-ng';

...
await waitForValueToStopChanging(() => getText(page, '#market_commodity_buyrequests'));

const text = await getText(page, '#market_commodity_buyrequests');
...
```

or just copy / paste code that implements this logic from library.